# Google Service Account. Unable to get access token for curl post https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-oauth

I am developing an API that connects to Google BigQuery. On my local development workspace, the application starts up fine and I am able to connect to Google Service Account successfully and get the results. However when I deploy it to the cloud cluster on IT environment, the application fails to connect to the Google Service Account. Below are the snippets from the console log.

Console log from local development workspace. This is successful.

```
2023-02-04 00:02:29.381  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : -------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.40.0 (gzip)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 808

2023-02-04 00:02:29.385  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : **curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.40.0 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' << $$$**
2023-02-04 00:02:29.913  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : Total: 808 bytes
2023-02-04 00:02:29.915  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : grant_type=xxxsome_valuexxxx
2023-02-04 00:02:30.118  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : -------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 04 Feb 2023 06:02:30 GMT
Via: 1.1 ippks41.company-dns.com:3128 (Cisco-WSA/12.5.2-011)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Referer
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

2023-02-04 00:02:30.124  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : Total: 1,083 bytes
2023-02-04 00:02:30.125  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : {"access_token”:”encrypted_access_token”,”expires_in":3599,"token_type":"Bearer"}
2023-02-04 00:02:30.153  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : -------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project_id/queries
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: <Not Logged>
User-Agent: gcloud-java/2.1.6 Google-API-Java-Client/1.32.1 Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.40.0 (gzip)
x-goog-api-client: gl-java/11.0.10 gdcl/1.32.1 mac-os-x/10.16
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip

2023-02-04 00:02:30.154  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'Authorization: <Not Logged>' -H 'User-Agent: gcloud-java/2.1.6 Google-API-Java-Client/1.32.1 Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.40.0 (gzip)' -H 'x-goog-api-client: gl-java/11.0.10 gdcl/1.32.1 mac-os-x/10.16' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Content-Encoding: gzip' -d '@-' -- 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project_id/queries' << $$$
2023-02-04 00:02:30.357  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : Total: 412 bytes
2023-02-04 00:02:30.358  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : {"query”:”select” data from table where condition,”requestId”:”some”_ecrypted_value,”useLegacySql":false}
2023-02-04 00:02:31.074  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : -------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Server: ESF
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 04 Feb 2023 06:02:31 GMT
Via: 1.1 ippks41.company-dns.com:3128 (Cisco-WSA/12.5.2-011)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Referer
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

2023-02-04 00:02:31.110  INFO 79746 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : Total: 1,000 bytes
```

Console log snippet from cloud cluster on IT/DEV environment. This fails to connect

```
2023-02-04 05:46:12.428  INFO 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : -------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.40.0 (gzip)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 808

2023-02-04 05:46:12.431  INFO 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : **curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.40.0 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' << $$$**
2023-02-04 05:46:23.325  WARN 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport   : exception thrown while executing request

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113) ~[google-http-client-1.40.0.jar!/:1.40.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84) ~[google-http-client-1.40.0.jar!/:1.40.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012) ~[google-http-client-1.40.0.jar!/:1.40.0]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:602) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:243) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:240) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) ~[guava-30.1.1-jre.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$AsyncRefreshResult.executeIfNew(OAuth2Credentials.java:567) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.asyncFetch(OAuth2Credentials.java:206) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:156) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:1022) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:96) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159) ~[google-cloud-core-http-2.1.2.jar!/:2.1.2]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:91) ~[google-http-client-1.40.0.jar!/:1.40.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565) ~[google-api-client-1.32.1.jar!/:1.32.1]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.queryRpc(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:650) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$35.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1284) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$35.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1281) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105) ~[gax-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryRetryHelper.run(BigQueryRetryHelper.java:85) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryRetryHelper.runWithRetries(BigQueryRetryHelper.java:49) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.queryRpc(BigQueryImpl.java:1280) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.query(BigQueryImpl.java:1268) ~[google-cloud-bigquery-2.1.6.jar!/:2.1.6]
```

Does this require any firewall setup on the cloud cluster? Or does it require any rules to enable access to the oauth url for googleapis? Or does it require any egress gateway setup?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: This looks like a networking problem, and it might be caused by [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access) being disabled, lack of egress internet access, or a firewall or VPC-SC configuration that disallows these network connections.